# List element value returns wrong values when accessing attribute

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a React component that I am trying to implement so that it can pass the particular value of the list item that a user clicks to a handle method.

```
var React = require('react');
var {connect} = require('react-redux');

export var Keyboard = React.createClass({
    handleKeyClick: function(keyClicked)
      {
          console.log(keyClicked.target.value);       
      },  
    render: function () {
        return (
            <ul onClick={(e) => this.handleKeyClick(e)}>
                <li value="1">1</li>
                <li value="2">2</li>
                <li value="3">3</li>
                <li value="4">4</li>
                <li value="5">5</li>
                <li value="6">6</li>
                <li value="7">7</li>
                <li value="8">8</li>
                <li value="9">9</li>
                <li value="0">0</li>
                <li value="B">B</li>
             </ul>  
        );
    }

 });
 export default connect()(Keyboard);
```

This works properly for all of the integer valued list items, but when I click the list item with the value of `B`, I receive 0 as my value, rather than `B`. Am I unaware of a restriction that only allows integers to be passed through `onClick` methods? Or perhaps I configured the `onClick` method incorrectly. Other examples of this situation:

- `value="3f"` returns `3`
- `value="H5"` returns `0`
- `value="35"` returns `35`

It seems apparent this is an issue with the String, but I don't know why. I'm using React version "^0.14.7"

Comment: Does it make any difference using `keyClicked.target.getAttribute('value')`?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_li_value.asp An issue easily searched for

Comment: W3C spec: http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#the-li-element

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Explanation

This isn't React's fault. This is defined in the [HTML5 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element) to behave this way. Per the link:

> **4.4.7 The `li` element**
>
> [...]
>
> **[Content attributes:](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-dfn-attributes)**
>
> [Global attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes)
>
>  If the element is a child of an [`ol`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ol-element) element: [`value`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#attr-li-value) - Ordinal value of the list item

Where `value` is defined as such:

> The `value` attribute, if present, must be a [valid integer](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#valid-integer) giving the ordinal value of the list item.

And a "valid integer" is defined as such:

> A string is a **valid integer** if it consists of one or more [ASCII digits](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#ascii-digits), optionally prefixed with a "-" (U+002D) character
>
> [...]
>
> The **rules for parsing integers** are as given in the following algorithm. When invoked, the steps must be followed in the order given, aborting at the first step that returns a value. This algorithm will return either an integer or an error.
>
> 1. Let `input` be the string being parsed.
> 2. Let `position` be a pointer into `input`, initially pointing at the start of the string.
> 3. Let `sign` have the value "positive".
> 4. [Skip whitespace.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#skip-whitespace)
> 5. If `position` is past the end of `input`, return an error.
> 6. If the character indicated by `position` (the first character) is a "-" (U+002D) character:
>
>    a. Let `sign` be "negative".
>
>    b. Advance `position` to the next character.
>
>    c. If `position` is past the end of `input`, return an error.
> 7. Otherwise, if the character indicated by position (the first character) is a "+" (U+002B) character:
>
>    a. Advance `position` to the next character. (The "+" is ignored, but it is not conforming.)
>
>    b. If `position` is past the end of input, `return` an error.
> 8. **If the character indicated by position is not an ASCII digit, then return an error.**
> 9. **[Collect a sequence of characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#collect-a-sequence-of-characters) that are ASCII digits, and interpret the resulting sequence as a base-ten integer. Let `value` be that integer**.
> 10. If `sign` is "positive", return value, otherwise return the result of subtracting `value` from zero.

In steps 8 and 9, it describes the behavior you see. The following examples:

- "3f" returns 3
- "H5" returns 0
- "35" returns 35

The first returns 3 because of step 9. It collects all the ASCII digits present if the first character is an integer, which is just 3, and interprets as an integer. In the second example, it returns 0 because of this:

> If the `value` attribute is present, user agents must parse it as an integer, in order to determine the attribute's value. If the attribute's value cannot be converted to a number, the attribute must be treated as if it was absent. The attribute has no default value.

Parsing fails on `H5` because the first character is not `+`, `-`, or an ASCII digit. Since the attribute is treated as absent as it's invalid, it's just 0, because `value` still needs to be a valid integer. If you pass an invalid integer that can't be parsed, the result of access attribute `value` is just 0, which is per the [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#reflecting-content-attributes-in-idl-attributes), in the applicable paragraph:

> If a reflecting IDL attribute has a signed integer type (`long`) then, on getting, the content attribute must be parsed according to the [rules for parsing signed integers](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#rules-for-parsing-integers), and if that is successful, and the value is in the range of the IDL attribute's type, the resulting value must be returned. **If, on the other hand, it fails or returns an out of range value, or if the attribute is absent, then the default value must be returned instead, or 0 if there is no default value.** On setting, the given value must be converted to the shortest possible string representing the number as a valid integer and then that string must be used as the new content attribute value.

Here, the `value` attribute is not defined to have a default value, and in this case `H5` isn't a valid integer so parsing fails and `0` is returned by specification. The last example returns 35 because it's a completely valid integer for `value`.

#### Solution

So instead, you can use [`Element.getAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute). Per the link:

> `getAttribute()` returns the value of a specified attribute on the element

No conversion happens in the method. It just gets the value as it does not need to convert to integer to figure out ordering as HTML does to determine where to place the `li`s. The [HTML Living Standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-getattribute) outlines the internal workings of this method. It just accesses a `NamedNodeMap` containing attributes and does not to any conversion. Thus:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("test").getAttribute("value"));
```

```html
<ul>
  <li value="Foobar" id="test">Test</li>
</ul>
```

This can be applied to your situation by doing this:

```
keyClicked.target.getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: Here from meta: this is exactly the answer this question needs.  Could have said `just use getAttribute()` but instead you explained _why_ the value property wasn't working.

Comment: But here it's a child of `ul`, not `ol`. I guess it doesn't make a difference: `<li value>` is always parsed as a number

Comment: @Scimonster Yeah, it doesn't matter if it's ol or ul. If it's ul then value means nothing, if it's ol it's used as ordinal value. value, independent of parent element of li, is always a number.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `value` when used with an `li` must be a number. I'd try this instead:

```
<li data-value="123abc">123abc</li>

keyHandler.target.getAttribute('data-value');
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`HTMLLIElement.value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLLIElement) *property* gets or sets the ordinal of the list element, and is always a number. If you want to get the string value, you have to read the `value` *attribute* instead.

```
keyHandler.target.getAttribute('value')
```